# Get the description of process using C#

Tags: c#, process

I want to access the description of running process of windows using c#. Can anybody tell me how it is possible

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (Process theprocess in processlist)
{
    label1.Text += theprocess.ProcessName+"\n";
}
```

I am getting processname from this code. But I want description too. Please tell me how can i do it

Comment: Did you try searching ?

Answer (score 2):

This should work: [FileVersionInfo Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (Process theprocess in processlist)
{
    label1.Text += theprocess.MainModule.FileVersionInfo.FileDescription + "\n";
}
```

You can get more properties:

[image: Properties]